# Character of $y=x^2cos\frac{1}{x}$ in $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to figure out the character of these functions:

- $$y=cos\frac{1}{x}$$
- $$y=xcos\frac{1}{x}$$
- $$y=x^2cos\frac{1}{x}$$
- $$y=x^3cos\frac{1}{x}$$
  in $x=0$ assuming that f(0)=0.

To do this, as tools, I have derivative / limits / asymptotic.

- In the fist one, I can easily see that with both the theorem on the limit of the derivative and the differential quotient, the derivative doesn't exist; can I assume that this means that the functions oscillate so fast that it doesn't have any tangent line?
- In the second line, same as the first one?
- Third one, the differential quotient lead me to $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$; does this means that, being the function squeezed by x^2, it stops to fluctuate?
- Last one, same as third, but I can achieve that $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ with the theorem of the limit of the derivative?
  Thanks a lot for the answer, I hope to have formatted this long question in a good way

Comment: All of them are applicable to squeeze theorem, and it can be used to show that the last three examples tend to $0$. The first example doesn't have a limit at 0.

Comment: Try and see if the second one is differentiable with the definition of derivative...

Comment: The second is not differentiable; i don't care about limit, and I assume that in 0 f=0; but, I meant, does the function oscillate in points near x=0?